# Is it possible to replace Honda Shine rear shock absorber by Gabriel or Escort?

Tags: honda, shock-absorber, shine-mc

I purchased my Honda Shine in 2011. The rear shock absorbers on the bike are not working properly from, thus I want to change it with the leading brads in shock absorber like Gabriel,Escort Etc. Out of these, which one should be preferable and can you suggest any other product for a Honda Shine rear suspension?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, questions about shopping assistance are off-topic due to the volatility of the information.

Comment: Gabriel is a leading brand, true. But do they make suspension setups for your make? Perhaps you should consider talking to a few local mechanics. To which setting do you want to the set the suspension to? You might want to consider the Pulsar 150 suspension which may or may not suit your needs. Pulsar being a heavier bikes, on your shine, you might find it a bit too stiff. I suggest you get it replaced with the stock ones and adjust it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I have replaced the original Honda Shine suspension with a Gabriel.  There are no significant differences in comfort.  Gabriel price is 1100, Honda price 1800.